# Kinect for Windows - PC Incompatibility

Tags: windows, kinect, incompatibility

I'm working for an University of Applied Sciences and we want to buy some Kinects together with some PCs for future research as well as student projects and we are currently in a stage where we want to define which hardware to use.

We have a Kinect for Windows sensor and we are testing it with a Dell PC `(Inspiron 15r 7520; Windows7 64bit, Intel i5-3210M @2.5GHz; 6GB RAM; USB 3.0)`.

We installed all the drivers for the 1.6 Version of the Kinect SDK but the PC only detects the Kinect camera once in a while.

In the device manger the `"Kinect for windows Audio Array Control"` and the `"Kinect for Windows Security Control"` show up but the `"Kinect for Windows"` Camera only shows up once in a while. If we plug and unplug the Kinect 10 (or 20 or 30 or 5) times the Camera is not detected 9 times. Then suddenly the camera is detected once and we are able to use it.

The next time we have to plug and unplug the camera 20 or 30 (or 2 or 5 or 10) times until the Camera is detected again. Then, we can plug and unplug the Camera 5 or 6 times and it is detected every single time.

Every time the camera is not detected a Windows USB Information (yellow triangle) pops up stating that a USB device was not detected.

We are quite sure that the Kinect sensor is not the problem because it works on 5 other PC without any problems. Then we thought about an USB Controller problem but after replacing the Mainboard and the USB Controller of the PC the error persists.

Are there any known PC - Kinect incompatibilities or can anybody think of a reason for this strange behavior?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this includes recognising the camera, but there are known issues with certain USB host controllers and version 1.6. If you haven't already, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663798.aspx) MSDN page under the "USB host controller compatibility" subheading.

It does mention two USB 3.0 controllers which are known to have issues. If you are using either the "Etron USB 3.0 Extensible Host Controller" or the "Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Controller" you might have your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.
We have two different Dell PCs both equipped with the Renesas USB 3.0 controller. On one of these systems the Kinect works without any problems, on the other system the Kinect shows the behavior described above.
So I'm not really sure if the USB Controller is the only Problem... Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have one of these incompatible USB 3.0 cards. From what I can tell, Kinect works fine with USB 2.0, and doesn't make use of the extra USB 3.0 bandwidth anyway. So do you think I could plug a USB 2.0 hub into the USB 3.0 bus and then use the Kinect over USB 2.0? Or do I need an entirely new PCI card?

Comment: @Wallacoloo I'm not sure what the compatibility issue was with those controllers, so I'm not sure. Might even be fixed with higher SDK versions. I haven't used the Kinect for around 2 years, my Kinect knowledge is quite rusty. Maybe someone else can answer...